# Polymorphic deserialization with root node

Tags: c#, json.net

Is it possible to make Newtonsoft.JSON to chose a class not based on `$type` property? For example, I want to deserialize the following JSON

```
{
  "widgets": [
    "circle": {
      "radius": 1
    },
    "rectangle": {
      "width": 1,
      "height": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

into the following class hierarchy

```
class WidgetList {
  IList<Widget> Widgets { get; set; }
}

abstract class Widget {}

class Circle : Widget {
  int Radius { get; set; }
}

class Rectangle : Widget {
  int Width { get; set; }
  int Height { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible in general, but not with the JSON you've provided, which is invalid. The typical approach involves the use of a custom JsonConverter.